# Croatian diacritic signs, mysql query problems

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I'm trying to create a mysql query for all elements starting with some user picked croatian alphabet  letter.

It all works fine for regular latin letters.

The problem I'm facing is that when i search something with S and say Š, I get both elements starting with S and Š, same goes for ČĆC.

```
$sql=" SELECT * FROM `default_subjects` where name like '{$keywords}%'";
```

Collation set is utf8_unicode_ci.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Did you try with utf8_general_ci collation set?

Comment: So you do ***not*** what to treat "Š" and "S" as the same letter?

Comment: Yeah I don't want to treat them as the same letter.

Comment: [This might help out](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,192187,207573#msg-207573)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"S" and "Š" are treated as the same letter due to the *collation* rules. This is supposed to be a good thing usually, as it allows "fuzzy" searches to a degree. If you do not want this and want only identical letters to be identical, change the collation to `utf8_bin` (binary collation). You can do this as a general setting for the table/column, or for each query as needed, depending on how often you need either functionality. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collate.html for the syntax.